# Terraform: Conditional statement blocks in aws_iam_policy_document?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

Is there a way to conditionally add `statement` blocks in `aws_iam_policy_document`? I'm looking for something like:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "PolicyAlways"

    ...
  }

  if (var.enable_optional_policy) {
    statement {
      sid = "PolicySometimes"

      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes. You can use a [`dynamic` block](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) with a boolean to optionally include the block.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "PolicyAlways"

    ...
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    # The contents of the list below are arbitrary, but must be of length one. 
    # It is only used to determine whether or not to include this statement.
    for_each = var.enable_optional_policy ? [1] : []

    content {
      sid = "PolicySometimes"
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to upvote this 10 times, super powerful!